# Downcast ComboBox в Win Forms

Tags: c#, ооп, классы, полиморфизм

У меня есть класс `FurnitureComboBox`, который является наследником `ComboBox`. 
Пытаюсь привести `ComboBox` к `FurnitureComboBox` (от базового к производному) и чего-то не понимаю.

Подскажите, как правильно закастить, чтобы я получил объект типа `FurnitureComboBox`.

```
 FurnitureComboBox furn = (FurnitureComboBox)furnitureTypeCB;
```

и получаю эксепшн вида:

> [image: пикча ошибки]

Comment: Покажите, как вы этот `Combobox` создали.

Comment: Привести ComboBox к FurnitureComboBox можно только если он фактически и есть FurnitureComboBox.